# How do I instruct NER SUTime to resolve-to-future?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I see that there is an option inside of SUTime to resolve ambiguous time references to the future, but I am not sure how to tell NER annotator to do so. For example, when annotating this sentence "let's go out on Friday" (and let's say that today's Sunday), I want SUTime to return next Friday's date, not the previous one, which appears by default, since it's closer to Sunday. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to provide your own grammar file. You can copy the default one from the corenlp. It should be located somewhere like `stanford-sutime-models-1.3.5.jar:edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt` 
Then add following code to the end of the section, that starts with comment `# Final rules to determine how to resolve date`:

```
  {  
   pattern: ( [ $hasTemporal ] ),
   action: VTag( $0[0].temporal.value, "resolveTo", RESOLVE_TO_FUTURE)
  }
```

This will tag all temporals to be resolved into the future. Note, that there're several predefined tags that resolves some time patterns into the past. You can delete/modify them too.

Then provide a resource path to your file to a TimeAnnotator constructor:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("sutime.rules", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt,PATH_TO_YOUR_RESOURCE_FOLDER/english.sutime.txt,edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt");
TimeAnnotator timeAnnotator = new TimeAnnotator("sutime", props);
```

There is also a small trick with a `DocDateAnnotation`. If you want time patterns like "on Friday at 7pm" to be resolved correctly, you should provide an iso formatted datetime (not only a date like YYYY-MM-DD) into a `DocDateAnnotation`.